# Permutations_Combination Discrete

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A subset of three distinct positive integers, each less than 20, is selected. a) How many subsets will contain all even integers? b) For how many subsets will the three integers have an even sum?

I know this problem is about combinations and permutations of a set for a) I'm not sure the distinct integers and also for part b) using subsets

Comment: Distinct integers means that the three integers are identifiably different. For example 1,2,3 would be valid. 1,2,2 would not be. A subset is a selection from a larger set. The set you have is the integers 1 through 19. Possible subsets include {2,3,4}, {1,11}, and so on. Something like {1,6,20} would not be a subset because the number 20 is not in the original set. A valid subset in your case is 3 positive integers, all less than 20, and none of them being the same.

Comment: It saves a fairly amount of counting that the integers must be distinct:  everything is about "drawing without replacement".  For the first part, how many even integers fall in the interval $ \ [1, 19] \ $ ?  How many ways are there to draw three even integers from that set without replacement?  For the second part, you must draw from the integers from 1 to 19 either three distinct _even_ integers, or one even integer and two distinct _odd_ ones.

Answer (score 1):

a) The numbers you have are $1$ through $19$, so there are $9$ even numbers in that group. You  must choose $3$ of them.
$$\binom{9}{3}=84$$

b) You have three integers and you need an even sum. Two evens added make even. Two odds added make even. An odd and even added make odd. As such the valid subsets have three even numbers, or two odd numbers and one even number. We've already found the all even scenario in part (a).

So we need to pick two odd numbers. There are $10$ to pick from, and we need $2$.
$$\binom{10}{2}=45$$
Then we need one even number, so
$$\binom{9}{1}=9$$
Take those together to get
$$\binom{10}{2}\binom{9}{1}=45\cdot9=405$$
So we have $84$ subsets with all even, and $405$ with two odd and one even, giving us
$$\binom{9}{3}+\binom{10}{2}\binom{9}{1}=84+405=489$$